# Using Sed in OSX to rename files

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I'm trying to do something as simple as rename all the files of a folder, using sed.
The purpose is to add a pattern in front of each file of the folder.

Before using "mv" command to actually rename the files, I'm using the "echo" command instead to ensure the filename is correct.

I'm on MAC OSX (using Iterm2). I found different solutions but it does not work at all. Here is what I did:

```
for f in *.mkv
do
    test1=`echo $f | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/^S01E(.*)$/g'`

    test2=$(echo $f | sed 's#^(.*)$#^S01E(.*)$#')

    echo "$f"
    echo "$test1"
    echo "$test2"
done

$test1 output: ^S01E(.*)$

$test2 output : the filename itselft
```

Comment: what does the `-E` key mean?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ - From `man sed` (on Mac OSX): `-E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).`

Comment: try my answer or this: `echo "$f" | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/^S01E\1$/'`

Comment: Not clear what exactly is the problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's analyze your `sed` commands:

**First sed command**

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)$/^S01E(.*)$/g'
```

The substitution-regex captures everything from beginning `^` to end `$` of line, using `(.*)`. Normally `sed` would require you to escape the parentheses: `\(.*\)`, but since you're using `-E` it's correct as printed. Next, it attempts to prefix the captured content with `S01E`. This where it goes wrong: The regex patterns `^ (.*) $` should not be repeated in the replacement. Instead, just put your prefix, followed by `\1` which represents the *first* capture group (parentheses). A second capture would end up in `\2` and so forth. And oh, the `g` modifier is not needed since there will only be a single replacement. So:

```
test1=`echo $f | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/S01E\\1/'`
```

result for file `01-somemovie.mkv`:

```
S01E01-somemovie.mkv
```

**Second sed command**

```
sed 's#^(.*)$#^S01E(.*)$#'
```

has a similar problem in the replacement part, plus you should escape the parentheses since it doesn't use `-E`. Do like this:

```
sed 's#^\(.*\)$#S01E\1#'
```

**Pro tip**

Since you are on Mac OSX, use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install the utility `rename`. Then just `rename --prepend S01E *.mkv` and you're done:

```
$ brew install rename
$ rename -n --prepend S01E *.mkv
'01-somemovie.mkv' would be renamed to 'S01E01-somemovie.mkv'
'02-somemovie.mkv' would be renamed to 'S01E02-somemovie.mkv'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the lines shall be:

```
test1=`echo "$f" | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/^S01E\1$/'`

test2=$(echo "$f" | sed 's#^\(.*\)$#^S01E\1$#')
```

Comment: You should use parentheses when possible `$(...)`, back-tics is old and obsoleted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed (but I think @grebneke gave two good options) or you can install `mmv`:

```
% brew install mmv
% mmv '*.mkv' 'S01E#1.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not need sed at all for this, it's just:

```
for f in *.mkv
do
    test1="S01E$f"

    echo "$f"
    echo "$test1"
done
```

Also, remember to always quote your shell variables unless you have a very specific reason not to and know exactly what the consequences/implications are. e.g. always do `echo "$f"`, not `echo $f` as you did in some places in your question.